# Why is EF Core treating my non-decorated class as an entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a simple class as follows:

```
public class NonEntity
{
   // some properties
}
```

I'm getting runtime errors that point to Entity Framework Core thinking this is a POCO (entity) class.  For example:

> The entity type 'NonEntity' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'

However, there is no `DbSet<NonEntity>` property in my DB context, and there are no attributes on the `NonEntity` class to suggest anything other than this being a standard class having nothing to do with my database.  What would cause EF Core to think otherwise?

Comment: `Task` is bad class name for the entity. You may have collision with `Task` from `System.Threading.Tasks`

Comment: Good point.  I was using a more specific name in my code, but simplified it for the question.  I have updated the question to remove the `Task` reference and thus the collision possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was happening because I was referencing the class inside of another class that *is* an entity:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<NonEntity> NonEntities
    {
        get
        {
           // some logic that converts entities to non-entities and returns them
        }
    }
}
```

Adding the `NotMapped` attribute to the property definition resolved it:

```
[NotMapped]
public List<NonEntity> NonEntities
```

By default, EF tries to map properties to the database.  The `NotMapped` attribute overrides this behavior.

Comment: I'm upvoting your question and answer because although to an experienced dev this may be an obvious thing SO is filled with inexperienced devs and I believe someone else is going to benefit from this. Make sure to come back and mark this answer as correct tomorrow.